Can a bad block from one partition affect other partitions?
I have an external SSD 1 TB plugged in to Linux-Laptop. I have created a small new partition - 10 GB size on it, so now I have 2 partitions on that SSD.
Both partitions are formatted with ext4 file system.
I download a lots of videos from youtube on that small 10-GB-partition every day.
If a bad sector/bad block appears on the small 10-GB-partition will it affect the other partition so that the files on it will be corrupted/broken/unreadable/lost?

AFAIK, no. SSDs, like HDDs, have spares they'll swap in that aren't assigned to any partition, with the bad block being marked as so and not used again. Depending on the size of the videos and how many accumulate on the 10GB partition, the small partition size may result in rewriting blocks unnecessarily if there's not enough free space to move data around on the partition from the firmware's point of view (there are writeups that explain why this is)

No. Any bad sectors/cells affects only data stored in that sectors/cells. With multiple bad sectors on drive/partition your OS could starting complain about damaged filesystem. However it complaints mostly for filesystem on which bad sectors are stored.
